# calculate location on additional Textbox on each button click

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Im working on adding a group of textbox each time a button is clicked, but the position of the next group of textbox should refer on the previously created textbox.

here is the screencap.

this is the first image before clicking the 'more' button
[image]

next is after clicking the more button once.
[image]

but after clicking again the more button. the space between each textbox is too far from the other.[image]

I know something is wrong in my location code. can someone help me check this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addbox.Click

    Dim Count = gbox2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count

    For i As Integer = 1 To 6
        Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "itemno2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 2
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(81, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "unit2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 3
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(142, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(254, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "itemdesc2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 4
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(417, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "requan2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 5
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "issuequan2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox3.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 6
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(94, 30 * Count)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(144, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "remarks2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox3.Controls.Add(txtbox)

        End Select

    Next
    'addbox.Visible = False
    save.Visible = False
End Sub
```

any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a variable that stores the current top position of the last textbox. On button click, add the height of your textbox to this variable + space between textbox rows. The initial top should be relative to your groupbox

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim currentTop As Integer = 5
Dim defaultHeight As Integer = 26

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Count = gbox2.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count

    currentTop += defaultHeight + 5

    For i As Integer = 1 To 6
        Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "itemno2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 2
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(81, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(43, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "unit2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 3
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(142, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(254, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "itemdesc2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 4
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(417, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "requan2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox2.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 5
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(56, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "issuequan2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox3.Controls.Add(txtbox)

            Case 6
                txtbox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(94, currentTop)
                txtbox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(144, 26)
                txtbox.Name = "remarks2" & (Count + 1)
                gbox3.Controls.Add(txtbox)

        End Select

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm, thanks for the help, but it seems that when I click again the "More" button no textbox shows up.

Comment: I created a button. Your button's name is addbox. Just change the name

Answer (score 1):

Use right tool for the job - [DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Instead of calculating positions and adding textboxes you can just add a row in `DataGridView`.
You can use two `DataGridView` controls for "Requisition" and for "Issuance" groups.

In the designer create two `DataGridView` and add columns you need. Then in
button click eventhandler you will add new row for both

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addbox.Click
    RequisitionDataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] {value1, value2, value2 })
    IssuanceDataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] {value6, value7})
End Sub
```

If you go further you can use `DataSource` property.
Create a class which represent one row of your data

```
Public Class Requisition
    Public Property ItemNo As Integer
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public ItemDescription As String
    Public Quantity As Decimal
End Class
```

Then create a `BindingList(Of Requsition)` and add it as data source in the DataGridiView

```
Public Class YourForm Inherits Form
    Private _requsitionData As New BindingList(Of Requsition)
    Private _issuanceData As New BindingList(Of Issuance) 

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponents()

        RequisitionDataGridView.DataSource = _requsitionData
        IssuanceDataGridView.DataSource = _issuanceData
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addbox.Click
        _requsitionData.Add(new Requisition())
        _issuanceData.Add(new Issuance())
    End Sub       

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but is there a way connecting DataGridView to a ms document template? what Im actually doing is whatever the value on the textbox should be copied to ms document through the use of bookmarks.

Comment: You can use `DataGridViewCell.Tag` for saving some information about bookmark. If you can show your code how you "connecting"?

Comment: this is how I connect textbox to ms document,  oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("bookmarkhere").Range.Text = textbox1.text

Comment: What value is "bookmarkhere"? I mean what is logic which connect "bookmarkhere" and textbox1

Comment: well it goes like this, "bookmarkhere" is declared on the ms document template so that whatever the value in textbox1 will be placed where the "bookmarkhere" is positioned in the ms document template

Comment: I mean how you know that "bookmark1" = textbox1 and not textbox2. Does all values from column "ItemDescription" goes under same bookmark?